# No memory for git clone

Tags: git, memory, memory-management, terminal, out-of-memory

I am on a shared hosting plan and I've done numerous git projects/commands with my web host. However I'm starting a new project which is still pretty small (4MB) compared to a bigger project (8MB) that I am able to successfully host with them without any issues.

When I ran `git clone ...` command, I got the following:

```sh
dokgu@domain.com [~/project.domain.com]# git clone git@gitlab.com:dokgu/project.git .
Cloning into '.'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1925, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1925/1925), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1642/1642), done.
remote: Total 1925 (delta 305), reused 1864 (delta 271), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1925/1925), 3.61 MiB | 8.54 MiB/s, done.
fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I already tried calling their technical support line but they weren't any help.

I was also trying to see the memory status of my account and this is what I found:

```sh
dokgu@domain.com [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        128963     126375       2587        245      17221      76232
-/+ buffers/cache:      32920      96042
Swap:         5999        362       5637
```

As you can see, I only have 2.5MB of available memory but when I try to list any processes that are taking memory:

```sh
dokgu@domain.com [~]# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dokgu          1  0.0  0.0  16628  2776 ?        SN   18:28   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -l
dokgu         52  0.0  0.0  18508  2064 ?        RN+  18:31   0:00 ps aux
```

What do I do from here when the hosting company's technical support isn't even able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is that `git index-pack`, which is threaded, is unable to create the threads which it uses, probably because it's artificially limited.  The relevant limit on Linux is `RLIMIT_NPROC`, which controls the number of threads that can be started at once.

Unfortunately, while `git index-pack` has an option to control the number of threads, it isn't possible to pass it when it's being used under the hood from `git fetch` or `git clone`, and there's no configuration option to control it.

You have some options here, though:

- Try to raise the number of allowed threads with `ulimit -u 1024` or something similar.  Smaller values may also meet your needs.  You can see the current values with `ulimit -u`.
- Ask your hosting provider to raise the number of allowed processes or threads for your account.
- Ask your hosting provider to provider a version of Git compiled without threads so that this isn't a problem, or compile one yourself.
- Clone th repository elsewhere and copy it over using SFTP.
- Find a different hosting provider whose limits are a little more reasonable.

Note that the problem is not free memory.  With `-m`, `free` prints megabytes, and you have 2.5 GB free, which should be sufficient.